# Sequelize: Problems with nested include / reverse association

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm pretty new to JS and Sequelize and I'm now facing problems when querying the following structure. Maybe I am totally missing some basic point here. Help is much appreciated.

Versions:

- node: 15.13.0
- sequelize: 6.6.2
- postgres: 13.3
- pg: 8.6.0
- pg-hstore: 2.3.3

### Structure

A flight belongs always to one user. Different users can create comments to one flight.

[image]

### Goal

When i select a flight by it's ID, i want to include the name of the user and i want to include all comments to that flight with the name of the user which created the comment.

### Problem

I'm able to include the comment to the flight. But I'm not able to achive the other goals. 
When I run:

```
await Flight.findOne({
      where: { id: flightId },
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: "user",
          attributes: ["id", "name"],
        },
        {
           model: FlightComment,
           as: "comments",
        },
      ],
    });
```

I will get the Error

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is not associated to Flight!

which is understandable. So I tried to add the reverse association to the Flight.

```
Flight.belongsTo(User)
```

After that I will get the error

> Flight.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

When I define a userId column in the FlightComment like:

```
  userId: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    references: {
      model: User,
      key: "id",
    },
  },
```

I will get the following error during database synchrinisation

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "FlightComments" CASCADE;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I read that you need to define all models in one file, but because of the many numbers of different models I want to keep things apart.

I didn't find any advise in the offical documentaion either.

### Model-Files

For every model I've created a own file (there will be alot of different models, so better keep things apart).

File for Flight:

```
const Flight = db.sequelize.define("Flight", {
  //Many beautiful attributes
});

Flight.hasMany(FlightComment, {
  as: "comments",
  foreignKey: {
    name: "flightId",
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  hooks: true,
});

//Another association

module.exports = Flight;
```

File for FlightComment:

```
const FlightComment = db.sequelize.define("FlightComment", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  message: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

module.exports = FlightComment;
```

File for User:

```
const User = db.sequelize.define(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true, 
    },
    //Many more attributes
  },
);

User.hasMany(Flight, {
  as: "flights",
  foreignKey: {
    name: "userId",
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

User.hasMany(FlightComment, {
  as: "comments",
  foreignKey: {
    name: "userId",
    allowNull: false,
  },
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  hooks: true,
});

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialise your db and its associations programmatically (with a file in the same folder as models) like:

```
'use strict'
 
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const config = {
  "username": "root",
  "password": "YOUR ROOT PASSWORD HERE",
  "database": "YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE",
  "dialect": "postgres"
}
const db = {}
 
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
 
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0)
    && (file !== basename)
    && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
 
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
 
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
 
module.exports = db;
```

With this you need to declare your model files like this:

```
module.exports = Flight = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Flight = sequelize.define('Flight', {
        //Many beautiful attributes
    })

    Flight.associate = models => {
        Flight.hasMany(models.FlightComment, { 
            as: 'comments',
            foreignKey: {
                name: "flightId",
                allowNull: false,
            },
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            hooks: true
        })
        Flight.belongsTo(models.User, {
            as: 'flight',
            foreignKey: {
                name: "flightId",
                allowNull: false,
            }
        })
    }

    return Flight
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. But there is also a drawback. 
You can't import any model via a simple require anymore into any other file. You need to import your db object and access the model via its key.

`const User = require("../model/User")` --> `const User = require("../config/db)["User"]`

With this VSCode isn't also able to identify a model as a Sequelize model class and will not offer any documentation on methods etc..

Comment: No you still can import models easily, it's done using `const {User} = require("../models")`.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I defined all models, which are depending on another, within one file.
This is not the solution I was searching for but it works...